# unsupervised ML clasifier for car price prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset from a car company. The dataset consists of multiple features. I want to predict the price of cars through unsupervised ML classifiers. I am not familiar with what classifier I use to predict the class label.

Comment: You must share your data samples and define the goal of the problem you want to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

predicting prices is a regression task, with classifier you may classify cars as cheap, medium and expensive. use clustering technique http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html.
if you dont have labeled data try to label some and use semi-supervised learning and label the rest automatically.